# Form acts odd when MaximizedBounds is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a Windows Form that has a specified location and size when it's maximized.
My problem is that when the form is maximized, the form moves to the Top Left of the Desktop and returns to the specified location...sometimes, leaving a blank background at the Top Left Area.

This is how I can reproduce the problem...

1) Create a new "Windows Forms Application" project named "MaximizingTest".
2) Add "this.MaximizedBounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);" under "InitializeComponent()".
3) Add SizeChanged Event.
4) Add "System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);"
5) Run the application pressing "F5".
6) Click the maximize button of the form and quickly click somewhere outside the form to lose focus.
7) The form is redrawn with the specified location(100,100) and size(200,200).
8) After a few secs, the form moves to the Top Left of the Desktop.
9) After a few more secs, the form returns to the specified location again.

I want to know why the form moves to the Top Left while the UI Thread is busy (Sleeping).

Thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MaximizingTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MaximizedBounds = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
        }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How many child controls are on the form?  Your posted code does not reproduce the problem of the form moving by itself to the corner and then back to the 100,100 position.  You have something else going on that we can't see.

Comment: Thanks Lars Tech! This problem happens on a plain Windows Form Project with the "MaximizedBounds" line under the "InitializeComponent();" and the "Form1_SizeChanged(...)" Event.  I tried again and found out that the problem tends to happen when the form is out of focus just after the MaximizeButton is clicked...I'm really sorry for the lack of information.   So please try losing the focus.

Comment: How does a form go out of focus if you are clicking on it?  There's a lot you aren't telling us.  Try creating a new project and replicate the problem, post that code.

Comment: Hi Lars Tech! I just edited the question exactly how this problem happens at my environment. I also tried on another machine and got the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the UI thread to sleep for 10 secs so of course each time the form is resized it will pause before redrawing. Why are you setting the UI thread to sleep? It seems to me that that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Vivek Verma! My actual code doesn't sleep but has some works to do (arranging dynamic controls) which takes less than 1 sec. I understand that redrawing would be paused while the UI thread is busy, but I don't get why the forms moves to the Top Left of the Desktop. This only happens when MaximizedBounds is changed...